# What is wrong with this function? Can't figure it out

Tags: python, function, types

I have been trying to get a function to work and I just cant seem to figure out why I get

```
TypeError: stringCounter() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
```

Everytime I run this code

```
def stringCounter(count):
     name ='Hi'
     formatString = "%s run count is %d"
     print formatString % (name, count)

test = stringCounter()

test.stringCounter(1)
```

I have tried adding self, messing with the variables passed what am I doing wrong? Thanks guys!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This:

```
test = stringCounter()
```

is obviously wrong, it calls the `stringCounter()` function without passing any arguments. Just as the error says. Just delete this line.

And this:

```
test.stringCounter(1)
```

is also wrong, there is no thing called `test` that contains a function called `stringCounter()` in your program. It should just be:

```
stringCounter(1)
```

Answer (score 4):

The error is self-explanatory:

```
test = stringCounter()
```

You're not passing any arguments to `stringCounter()` here, when one (namely `count`) is expected. You likely simply want

```
stringCounter(1)  # don't assign this to anything, it returns None
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
test = stringCounter

test(1)
```

Or directly:

```
stringCounter(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are calling stringCounter with no arguments in the line

test = stringCounter()

it looks like you are trying to instantiate it, but it is a function, not a class.

Answer (score 0):

You're not passing any parameters to the function `test = stringCounter()`

And this line doesn't make sense since test is None (the previous function returns nothing)

```
test.stringCounter(1)
```